# Is the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the graph of a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ at least 1?

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. We define the graph of $f$ to be the set
$$\text{graph}\,f=\{(x,f(x)):x\in [0,1]\}.$$

Is
$\mathcal{H}^1(\text{graph}\,f)\ge 1$, where $\mathcal{H}^1$ is the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I know that if $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, then it is differentiable almost everywhere and
$$\mathcal{H}^1(\text{graph}\,f)=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx\ge 1.$$

I believe that the result still holds in the case where $f$ is just continuous but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: If $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then ${\rm diam }\,U\le {\rm diam }\,U_x$ where $U_x$ is the projection of $U$ on the $x$ axis. This should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $f$ doesn't even need to be continuous.  Hint: Consider the projection $\pi_1: (x,y) \to x$ which maps the graph onto $[0,1]$.